# How to create an empty file from command line

Tags: command-line

How can I create an empty file from the command line?

Answer (score 284, accepted):

Use the [`touch`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_%28Unix%29) command:

```
The touch utility sets the modification and access times of files to the
current time of day. If the file doesn't exist, it is created with
default permissions.
```

Example:

```
touch newfile
```

Comment: You can use `touch newfile.txt` or some other extension, too (if you need to specify the extension).

Comment: @gotqn for python touch newfile.py and for ruby newfile.rb ?

Comment: But if `newfile` already exists and isn't empty, then `touch newfile` will leave you with a *nonempty* file.  Maybe not what you wanted.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune I think If `newfile` already exists, `touch` command will just **update the timestamp of file** (which is what command exactly for) without editing the contents of file.

Comment: You don't have to think that;  it's true!  But it's not what the question asked.

Answer (score 93):

```
> newfile
```

Will also **create** an empty file. If the file does already exist, it will be **truncated** (emptied). To keep the file contents, use `>>` for appending as in:

```
>> file
```

Even if the file exists, the contents will be untouched.

**Edit**: If you don't have any content to type, this one is faster:

```
user@host$ :> newfile
user@host$ :>> new_or_existing_file
```

Note. `:` is the command here. It is not part of the prompt.

---

If you want to create as root

```
: | sudo tee thefile
```

To not truncate existing file:

```
: | sudo tee -a thefile
```

Comment: Now that's new. Is it bash-specific?

Comment: I don't think so. Any shell which allows redirection of output stream to a file should support this. This will truncate the file if it already exists. touch is safe to use if you don't want to empty it.

Comment: Wow now I think this is called cheating the system

Comment: I understand that `:` is a null command, but could you explain why `: > file` is faster than `> file`

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut because you don't have to press `Ctrl+D`

Answer (score 16):

```
cat /dev/null > file1.ext
```

the exact way there is also another way

```
echo "" > file2.ext
```

The difference is file1.ext will be zero bytes and file2.ext would be one byte. You can check this by

```
ls -l file*.*
```

Comment: No, 'echo "" >' does not create an empty file, it creates a file containing a newline. If you for some reason want to use echo to create an empty file you will have to use 'echo -n "" >', or simply 'echo -n >'

Answer (score 10):

Using `vim` editor you can also create an empty file.

```
vim filename
```

Then save

```
:wq
```

Comment: Well, in this case not any text editor but `vim`.

Comment: This is not from the command line. Perhaps if you post a vim one-liner.

Answer (score 3):

The command

```
echo -n > file
```

creates an empty file, if your version of `echo` supports the -n switch.

Or you could use `printf`

```
printf '' > file
```

Comment: printf gave me a permission error even as sudo

Answer (score 3):

In general, creating any regular<sup>1</sup> file on Linux involves  [`open(2)` ,`openat(2)`, and `creat(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) system calls (and specifically with `O_CREAT` flags). That means if you call any command-line utility that does these system calls, you can create a new empty file.

Most commonly new filename is created with something like this:

- `touch /tmp/new_file`
- `: > /tmp/new_file`
- `true > /tmp/new_file`
- `> /tmp/new_file` ( bash shell only )

[touch](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/touch.1.html) is a standalone utility. Its original purpose is to update the access and modification time of a file, however if the file does not exist - it will be created. Note also that a filename `-` is treated specially, so if you do want to create a file that is named literally `-`, you'll have to enclose that into single or double quotes.

By contrast, `>` is a shell redirection operator for [stdout stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams).  The `>` operator  specifically calls the `openat()` system call with  `O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC`  flags. That means, if the filename does not exist - it will be created, and if it does - the data will be truncated (and therefore gone, so `>` should be used with care). In most shells nowadays `true` or `:` is a built-in , so  doing `: > /tmp/new_file` is going to be more efficient, although marginally compared to `touch /tmp/new_file`.

But of course it does not stop there. As mentioned, anything that can perform `open()`, `openat()` and, `create()` syscalls will create a file. Hence, we can do:

- `true|dd of=/tmp/newfile`
- `truncate --size 0 /tmp/new_filename.txt`
- `cp /dev/null /tmp/null_file`
- `true|tee /tmp/some_other_file`
- `mktemp` or `tempfile` ( for creating temporary files that do not need to exist between reboots !)

Of course, all the above mentioned utilities do not exclusively create files. But they perform the necessary syscall and that allows us to adapt the commands.

---

Of course, at the level of programming or scripting we may want to create a file as well, especially for efficiency purposes (because calling external commands such as `touch` from a Perl script or Python will require additional resources).

Python one-liner:

```
$ python -c 'import sys,os;f=sys.argv[1];os.utime(f,None) if os.path.exists(f) else open(f,"a").close' myfile.txt
```

We can make it shorter with this:

```
$ python -c 'import sys,os;f=sys.argv[1];'$'\n''with open(f,"a"): os.utime(f,None)' mysecondfile.txt
```

And in Perl:

```
$ perl -e 'open(my $fh,">","/tmp/perlfile")'
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Other types of files such as hard/soft links,character or block special devices, directory,named pipes, or sockets require entirely different syscalls.