# Create file in home directory from another directory

Tags: command-line, scripts

I know `touch` & `echo` for creating an empty file. But how can I create an empty file in the home directory in one line? I have tried `touch ~/boo.txt` but it's creating the file. I'm new to shell, I need to know two approaches of creating an empty file in Home directory from another directory. TIA

Comment: I can't get what is wrong with `touch ~/boo.txt` ...

Comment: @Ravexina I'm not sure also. I tried in lab computer and it was working but it's not working in my own pc

Comment: Please explain what exactly you want to achieve. Your question is absolutely unclear.

Comment: Technically, this is a duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/q/21556/295286

Comment: See the linked post, there's plenty of methods to do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an alternative to touch, just redirect nothing to a file:

```
> ~/newfile
```

**Important:** it will overwrite the file if it's already there, however you can use:

```
(set -C; > ~/newfile)
```

so it's not going to be overwritten if it's already exist.

here is another fun way to do this:

```
cat <<<"" >> ~/newfile
```

the `cat` is unnecessary so we can just use:

```
>> ~/newfile
```

Answer (score 0):

`touch /home/username/newfile.txt`

note:file and directory names are case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `truncate` command, which will create the file if it doesn't exist. Be warned that this will also empty an existing file.

```
truncate -s 0 ~/newfile
```